# SPRING : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: jsp, redirect, spring-mvc

Here is the screen shot for the error i am facing.

Problem is that forgot-password is again appending in the URL.(See Address Bar of the attached image)

[image]

My **Controller** is below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/forgot-password")
public class ControllerForgotPassword {
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView sendMail(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String email = (String) request.getParameter("email");
        boolean flag=serviceForgotPassword.checkEmail(email);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        if(flag)
        {
            modelAndView.addObject("message", "Mail has been sent to your mail box");
            modelAndView.setViewName("forgot-password-sucess");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        else
        {
            modelAndView.addObject("message", "Please Enter Valid email address");
            modelAndView.setViewName("forgot-password");
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
}
```

The **forgot-password.jsp** content is following:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt"
    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Forgot-Password</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="color:red;">${message}</p>
<form action="forgot-password/email" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send Mail">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use `modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/forgot-password-sucess");` in the `sendMail` method, but then i am not able to receive the message from controller.

**EDIT :**

If i add `<form action="/CabFMS/forgot-password/email" method="POST">` that is my **context/project** name then it works with no problem.

Do i need to add my context name everywhere in the from action along with controller mapping?

Can't i use just `forgot-password/email` in the form action??

Please Help.

Regards,

Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form action needs to be absolute to match your controller. It is currently specifying a relative path.

```
<form action="/forgot-password/email" method="POST">
              |
           add this leading slash
```

**Edit:** This will only work if the application is at the root context.

If the application is deployed to a different context, the context will also need to be added to the form's action attribute.

A better approach would be to keep the relative path and use the HTML `<base>` tag on the page which should *include* the context - see [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag). I tend to write Spring applications with the following in the JSP.

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
```

That way, relative paths in the page can naturally be resolved against the correct context, wherever that may be.

Comment: Using `<form action="/forgot-password/email" method="POST">` produces 404 not found error with URL in address bar `http://localhost:8080/forgot-password/email`. But if i add `<form action="/CabFMS/forgot-password/email" method="POST">` that is my context/project name then it works with no problem. Do i need to add my context name everywhere in the from action along with controller mapping. Can't i use just **forgot-password/email**??

Comment: OK I understand. Sorry I missed the context in the image. I have updated my answer.